# Is there an English expression from Latin for "in writing", "written", etc?

Tags: expressions, latin

Is there a Latin expression that is now used in English for "written"? For example, "Here is my request in written form." - to replace "in written form"? Or, "We took written notes.", you get the idea.

Comment: We don't do Latin here, except as etymology or if the term has entered into *English* usage. Perhaps you might want to rephrase to avoid having the question closed.

Comment: Of course, I am looking for a Latin term that's used in English, like "et cetera", "per personem", and the like.

Comment: What about Greek? There's *orthography*

Comment: So that would be "Here's our request in orthography"? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: Why does it have to be Latin?  What's wrong with "here's my written request."?

Answer (score 2):

The Latin for writing is *scriptum*, so you could try

> in scriptum

but it's not used.

Answer (score -1):

The English equivalent of the Latin scriptum (for writing) is "scribe."

So I would test permutations of English words using scribe; inscribe, transcribe, etc.

Comment: Also "Described".  Though that word has lost much of its "written" connotation.

Comment: @SimonB: That's your contribution. I was just giving examples (of where to look.)